# Backlinks : having a link back to my site that I have an affiliate to

Tags: seo, backlinks

If I have a link to my site and I use an affiliate like back to the site that has a link to my site. Would that hurt my SEO rating or would it help it?

Answer (score 1):

**A few things to consider when backlinking or link sharing.**

Just make sure to keep it relevant. In other words, since nothing is 100% certain, I tend to only share links with sites that have similar content on a whole. Do not mix a pet website with a tire and wheel shop.

I think thats when you risk the chance of getting dinged. Only time I think nothing of irrelevant content is if it Google Adwords are placed. Other than that I do not expect to see a write up about sneakers when looking at Apple products.

**Prime Example here on StackExchange:**

Look how quick StackExchange members control the flow and placement of content on here, for the sake of keeping relevancy. It all makes a huge difference, in the search results.